# Search based on multiple parameters from UItableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, search, model-view-controller, swift3

I required to make search in UITableView where multiple data is coming (name, contact number, email, status etc.) And user can make search by name, or phone number to search the record. And data is handled through models, means an array have the objects in it. So, how to make search this way i have no idea.

Displaying data in UITableViewCell this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: VisitorsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VisitorsCell", for: indexPath) as! VisitorsCell

    let dss:VisitorsDs = VisitorsArray[indexPath.row] as! VisitorsDs

    dss.ageFromDate = ds.age
    cell.lblAge.text = dss.ageFromDate
    cell.lblName.text = dss.namePlain
    cell.lblMobile.text = dss.mobilePlain
    cell.lblPurpose.text = dss.purpose
    cell.lblParentsName.text = dss.parentsName
    cell.lblTime.text = dss.time
    cell.lblDate.text = dss.date
    cell.lblClinic.text = dss.clinic

    return cell

}
```

Update:

```
let dss:VisitorsDs = VisitorsArray as! VisitorsDs

    let filteredArray = self.VisitorsArray.filter(using: {($0.dss.namePlain.contains(txtSearch.text)) || ($0.dss.mobilePlain.contains(txtSearch.text))})
```

Comment: Use `filter()` or `NSPredicate` on each of the properties where user can search of `VisitorsDs`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `namePlain` and `mobilePlain` are strings. Try this -

```
let filteredArray = self.VisitorsArray.filter({($0.namePlain.contains(yourSearchTextField.text)) || ($0.mobilePlain.contains(yourSearchTextField.text))})
```

Comment: It is a string actually, but it can not be accessed directly. as i am using the instance of the class to access it.

Comment: @iPhone6 Okay use the above code in the answer. And use `filteredArray` as your datasource

Comment: error: type of expression is ambigious wthout more context

Comment: @iPhone6 Why u are using `dss` after $0. $0 is instead dss meaning your object of type `VisitorsDs`

Comment: tried that also, same error. That's why tried with dss

Comment: @iPhone6 Type cast $0 as VisitorsDs and don't use dss

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155597/discussion-between-iphone-6-and-aditya-srivastava).

Comment: @iPhone6 Sure we can. But what's the problem now?

Comment: @iPhone6 Nice.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your filtering needs to be done on the objects in your array, before you call tableview.reloadData()

You can't filter any more records after you forward to the table view how many rows are to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller), which is designed for this purpose.  [This tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) appears to be exactly what you're looking for--how to integrate search into a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got myself, but thanks to @Aditya Srivastava and @Larme for putting me on right track.

```
arrSearchResults = recentVisitorsArray.filter{ ($0.namePlain.contains(txtSearch.text!)) || ($0.mobilePlain.contains(txtSearch.text!)) }
```

mistake i was doing was:

```
 //var recentVisitorsArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

correct way is:

```
var recentVisitorsArray = [RecentVisitorsDs]()
var arrSearchResults = [RecentVisitorsDs]()
```